# Android issue displaying day of week string

Tags: android, sqlite, time, gregorian-calendar

I have seen many examples of working with dates in Android using Calendar and GregorianCalendar classes.
Recently I came across the following in Android Developers `Time` documentation:

> The Time class is a faster replacement for the java.util.Calendar and java.util.GregorianCalendar classes. An instance of the Time class represents a moment in time, specified with second precision.

This prompted me to replace all the Calendar functions with the faster Time class functions.

Here is my code for reading the date stored in the SQLite database:

`// extract milliseconds (long) value from SQLite database

Long timeLong = note.getLong(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE));

Time currentTime.set(timeLong);`

Here is the partial code for preparing the integer values for populating the date picker and displaying the formatted date string in the mPickDate button:

```
    mDay = currentTime.monthDay;             // Day of the month (0-31)
    mMonth = currentTime.month;              // Month (0-11)
    mYear = currentTime.year;                // Year 
    mPickDate.setText(currentTime.format("%A, %d %b %Y")); // using strftime equivalent to dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy");
```

Note the format %A used to get the long string for the day of the week.
This part of the formatting code works perfectly well and displays the correct string with the formatted date, including the correct day of the week.

Clicking on the mPickDate button invokes the DatePicker widget, which allows for changing and setting the new date.

The following code shows the handling of the newly selected date from the DatePicker:

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // new method using Time class
                currentTime.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);

                mPickDate.setText(currentTime.format("%A, %d %b %Y"));

                // old method using GregorianCalendar class
                //mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                //mPickDate.setText(dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));                    
            }
        };
```

The mPickDate button gets the correct date string displayed, as selected in the Date Picker, except for the day of the week (%A), which is always shown as Sunday. Why ?

Note that mPickDate.SetText code is identical to the one used earlier to format the button date string, extracted from the SQLite database field.

I had to modify the above code, by adding an extra line of code to set the date value in the currentTime Time object once again:

```
            currentTime.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
            currentTime.set(currentTime.toMillis(true));
            mPickDate.setText(currentTime.format("%A, %d %b %Y"));
```

My question is: why it was necessary to use the currentTime.set procedure twice in the above DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener code, in order to get the day of the week string to display correctly ?

Would this possibly be an issue with Android `Time`code itself (using SDK version 16) ?